# Selecting the platform for a project

Tags: .net, angularjs, node.js, cordova, project

I am making a project which consists of a Web app, a mobile app integrated to it and a common DB of course.
The part where i am confused is that which platform to use? .Net, MEAN Stack or Cordova?
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is going to trigger a LOT of primarily opinion based answers. Which is not what SO is for. Please refer to [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Whichever you are most comfortable with.

Our comfort is of no use to you.